# Rename a file to trash

Tags: c

I am using rename function (C, under ubuntu) to move file from one folder to another when trying: 
    `rename("./t2.c", "./this/then_this/it_works.c");`
it works wonders, removes the file from current folder and moves it to the then_this folder under name.

but when i try this:
    `rename("./t2.c", "~/.local/share/Trash/files/it_works.c");`
it just doesn't work, but in terminal typing in "cd ~/.local/share/Trash/files/it_works.c" does open the trash bin.

So what i'm trying to do is move a file to trash bin(delete it). Could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `~` only works in the shell. Replace with the full absolute path (e.g. `/home/user1031204/.local/...`) & re-try.

Comment: many thanks it works :D but what if I want to use this somewhere else? i would need to learn their username wouldn't i?

Comment: @user1031204: You could use `getuid()` combined with `getpwuid_r()` to find out the user's home directory (look at `pw_dir`).

Answer (score 4):

`~` is an handy shortcut available only in shell. You can achieve a similar behaviour by using [`getenv("HOME")`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/getenv.html) and concatenate it with the target directory.

```
snprintf(buffer, size_of_buffer, "%s/.local/share/Trash/files/it_works.c",
         getenv("HOME"));
```

Remember to `#include <stdlib.h>` and have a buffer which is at least `PATH_MAX` bytes long (`limits.h`) to store the result.

Comment: Nobody can predict how long the result will be. Environment variables can hold as many data as the user wants. Prefer `snprintf`, which lets you inform the maximum buffer size, otherwise your application is susceptible to a stack or heap-overflow, e.g.: `$ HOME=\`perl -e 'print "A" x 4096'\`; ./your_program`.

Answer (score 4):

[realpath()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/realpath.3.html) will be helpful here.  You may want to look at [glob()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/glob.3.html) and [wordexp()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) as well.

Comment: @timbo - yes, the tilde has no special meaning in a file path.  It is only meaningful to shells which are programmed to interpret it.